# Fragment continue recreates again when back pressed several times before app closes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, onbackpressed

There's an issue I am trying to solve in my app, I have a navigation drawer with 7 fragments when the app opens, and/or If I back from a details activity if I click on the back button, I see the fragment recreated again, and I had to press the back button several times again and again to close the app

problem in GIF

[image]

**MainActivity**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var APP_START_TIME: Long = 0


    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private var _binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var postViewModel: PostViewModel
    private var _navGraph: NavGraph? = null
    private val navGraph get() = _navGraph!!
    lateinit var adView: AdView
    private var adRequest: AdRequest? = null


    private val applicationScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Unconfined)


    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        adView.destroy()
        adRequest = null
        _binding = null
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        APP_START_TIME = System.currentTimeMillis()
        _binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)


        adView = AdView(this)
        delayedInit()
        postViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[PostViewModel::
        class.java]


        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)


        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout


        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment?

        if (navHostFragment != null) {
            navController = navHostFragment.navController
        }




        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_accessory,
                R.id.nav_arcade, R.id.nav_fashion,
                R.id.nav_food, R.id.nav_heath,
                R.id.nav_lifestyle, R.id.nav_sports, R.id.nav_favorites, R.id.settingsFragment
            ), drawerLayout
        )



        setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration)
        setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController)

        _navGraph = navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.mobile_navigation)


        onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this /* lifecycle owner */,
            object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                    // Back is pressed... Finishing the activity

                    finish()
                }
            })
}

//    override fun onStart() {
//        super.onStart()
//    }


    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        adView.pause()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        adView.resume()

        postViewModel.currentDestination.observe(this) { currentDestination ->

            Log.w(TAG, "currentDestination: at first run is $currentDestination")

            navGraph.setStartDestination(currentDestination)
            navController.graph = navGraph


        }

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            Log.d(TAG, "addOnDestinationChangedListener: " + destination.id)

            if (destination.id != R.id.settingsFragment
                && destination.id != R.id.aboutFragment
                && destination.id != R.id.privacyPolicyFragment
            ) {
                postViewModel.saveCurrentDestination(destination.id)
            }

        }
    }

    private fun requestHomeBanner() {

        adRequest = Constants.callAndBuildAdRequest()
        adView.adListener = object : AdListener() {

            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onAdFailedToLoad: ${adError.cause.toString()}")
                Log.e(TAG, "onAdFailedToLoad: ${adError.responseInfo.toString()}")
            }

        }



        adRequest?.let { adView.loadAd(it) }


    }



    private fun delayedInit() = applicationScope.launch {
        binding.adViewContainer.addView(adView)
        adView.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        adView.setAdSize(Constants.GET_AD_SIZE(this@MainActivity))


        val testDeviceIds = listOf("048DC5C3C06FBD17D9AD205151167F48")
        val configuration = RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(testDeviceIds).build()
        MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration)


        if (Utils.hasInternetConnection(this@MainActivity)) {
            requestTheLatestConsentInformation(this@MainActivity)
            MobileAds.initialize(this@MainActivity) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onInitCompleted")
            }

            requestHomeBanner()
        }
    }


    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

}
```

### My tries to solve

1. I tried to add the following code inside `OnBackPressedCallback`

```
navGraph.clear()
binding.drawerLayout.removeAllViews()
binding.navView.removeAllViews()
```

2. also I tried to add `onBackPressedDispatcher` callback inside `addOnDestinationChangedListener`

```
            onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this /* lifecycle owner */,
              object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                  override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                      // Back is pressed... Finishing the activity

                     navController.clearBackStack(destination.id)
                      finish()
                 }
               })
```

3. I tried to handle back pressed from the fragment itself not from the activity like the following

```
requireActivity()
            .onBackPressedDispatcher
            .addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Fragment back pressed invoked")

//                    hideShimmerEffect()
                    // Do custom work here
                 



                    requireActivity().finish()

              //       if you want onBackPressed() to be called as normal afterwards
                    if (isEnabled) {
                        isEnabled = false
                        requireActivity().onBackPressed()
                    }
                }
            })
```

4. I tried to pop the back stack or clear it by adding the following two lines to my above code

```
findNavController().popBackStack()
findNavController().clearBackStack(R.id.nav_home)
```

5. and finally I tried to edit the `onSupportNavigateUp` like the following

```
 override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return if(supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0){
            navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
        }else {
            finish()
            super.onSupportNavigateUp()

        }
    }
```

and this is my last edited code, all this tries not solved the problem

Comment: Try to remove the observer by designating a variable for the observer: `postViewModel.currentDestination.removeObserver` in `onDestroy`...

Comment: @zain `Type mismatch.
Required:
Observer<in Int!>
Found:
MainActivity`

Comment: Not sure how do you define the currentDestination; but see this [demo](https://pastebin.com/A0RSAmK9)

Comment: @zain I didn't create an observer on it in the main activity, I observe it directly, I used [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69591594/7639296) but in kotlin, in ViewModel, it's defined like this `val currentDestination = dataStoreRepository.readCurrentDestination.asLiveData()`

Comment: I need to check it but can't now; something else that you'd try to removeOnDestinationChangeListener https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#removeOnDestinationChangedListener(androidx.navigation.NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener) in `onDestroy()`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to go back to initial activity or quit the app in case of a single activity app add

```
 android:noHistory="true"
```

in your Manifest file inside the activity tag

Comment: It's not single activity, I have another activity **Details Activity** which shows the item details

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i think it's because you are setting startDestination for second time in onResume(). First one was setted defaultly in onCreate(). That's why it stacks and you happen to press back button twice.
Moving below code to onCreate() might help:

```
        postViewModel.currentDestination.observe(this) { currentDestination ->

            Log.w(TAG, "currentDestination: at first run is $currentDestination")

            navGraph.setStartDestination(currentDestination)
            navController.graph = navGraph


        }

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            Log.d(TAG, "addOnDestinationChangedListener: " + destination.id)

            if (destination.id != R.id.settingsFragment
                && destination.id != R.id.aboutFragment
                && destination.id != R.id.privacyPolicyFragment
            ) {
                postViewModel.saveCurrentDestination(destination.id)
            }

        }
```

Comment: I moved it to onCreate but it doesn't effect

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this function to start your fragments:

```
private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment?) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
            fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment)
                .commit()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I using android navigation component not the old way

Answer (score -1):

In java i have used this type of method. Don't know weather it will works on you or not.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
         finish();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately not working